# Javascript Regex - Remove uncaptured group

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to keep the `20V` from the following string, and remove everything else:

```
Range    20V    0.5A
```

I am using the following regex to capture the 20V:

```
/[^0123456789]*(\d+V).*/g
```

So in Javascript, how do I remove everything that is not captured from the string? I tried this and it removed everything:

```
var myString = "Range   20V   0.5A"
var newString = myString.replace(/[^0123456789]*(\d+V).*/g, "")
```

Also if possible, please suggest a better regex, I feel that `[^0123456789]` is quite silly.

Comment: `\D` = `[^0123456789]`

Comment: @PranavCBalan OH, thanks :P I actually did not know about that, I just went through a whole set of online interactive tutorial and apparently they missed out `\D`.

Comment: `var newString = myString.replace(/\D*(\d+V).*/g, "$1")`

Comment: or `var newString = myString.replace(/.*?(\d+V).*/g, "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`\D` which is equivalent to `[^0123456789]` ( or `[^0-9]` )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-digit). Then you can use `$1` get captured string in **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

```js
var myString = "Range   20V   0.5A"
var newString = myString.replace(/\D*(\d+V).*/g, "$1")
console.log(newString);
```

---

Or simply get the captured string using **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

```js
var myString = "Range   20V   0.5A"
var newString = myString.match(/\D*(\d+V).*/)[1];
console.log(newString);
```

Comment: match can return null as well

Comment: How exactly did the `match` work here? I tested with index `0` and it returned the whole string. Also if I keep the `g` modifier it wouldn't work as well. Does `match` ignore captured group?

Comment: @Liren :  for more info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Description

Answer (score 1):

Why remove everything but your desired substring, instead of capturing your desired substring directly?

```
"Range   20V   0.5A".match(/\d+V/)[0]
// => "20V"
```

Comment: @gurvinder372: Then you add a guard; this is proof-of-concept, a one-liner without even variables, obviously not how you'd write it in real code.

Answer (score 1):

Your are almost there, just change two things

1) Change your regex to

```
/\d+V/g
```

2) And use `match` and then `join`, instead of `replace`

**DEMO**

```js
var myString = "Range   20V   0.5A"
var matches = myString.match(/\d+V/g);
var finalOutput = matches ? matches.join() : "";
alert(finalOutput);
```